# Delete /x02 character from a file

Tags: delete

I am trying to delete x02 character from a file, I can easily delete x02 from a file using `sed -i 's/\x2//g'` command. Problem here is I don't want to delete x02 character which immediately starts with `I`. Except that I want to delete all other x02 characters.

Example:

File data:

```
I^A12^Agop^Bal^BI^A3^B^B4^Aramu^BI^A56^Asubbu^BI^A78^Asai^B
```

Expected output:

```
I^A12^Agopal^BI^A34^Aramu^BI^A56^Asubbu^BI^A78^Asai^B
```

Answer (score 1):

You could explicitly match anything but `I`:

```
sed -i 's/\x02\([^I]\)/\1/g
```

This matches any pair of characters which are any character other than `I` preceded by `\x02` and replaces it with the second character.

Comment: Thanks Gilles, It was working fine if there is one  x02. If I have more then one x02 it not working fine.  In the above example, it was unable to delete x02 character between 3 and 4 I^A12^Agopal^BI^A3^B4^Aramu^BI^A56^Asubbu^BI^A78^Asai^B

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -e '
  s/\(\x02\)\1\1*//g;   # erase 2 or more consecutive STX chars
  s/\x02\([^I]\)/\1/g;  # erase the STX only if followed by a non-I char
' yourfile
```

Comment: Thanks, it was working fine. Just out of curios, just want to know. What if I want to check for both I and /x01 character instead of only I before deleting /x02.

Comment: Can you rephrase your question to make it unambiguous?

Comment: In below example, if I want to delete /x02 which immediately starts with I and \x02                                    I^A12^Agop^Bal^BI^A3^BI^B4^Aramu^BI^A56^Asubbu^BI^A78^Asai^B   Here I don't want to delete I in 3^BI^B4 as it doesn't have immediate I and /x02

Comment: Before you post, read it to ensure it is very clear. For example, your statement, `Here I don't want to delete I in 3^BI^B4 as it does't have immediate I` which contradicts with your assertion in the beginning that you want to delete /x02 which immediately starts with I` So it's not clear whether you are focussing on deleting I or deleting \x02.